# How to resolve "DisplayDocTitle key is not set to true" error generated by PAC tool in a pdf generated using apache FOP

Tags: pdf, xslt, apache-fop

I am trying to generate pdf using ApacheFOP and making it accessible. When I am running PAC tool to find out the accessibility errors we are getting the error “DisplayDocTitle key is not set to true”.Below is the xsl:

```
            <pdf:dictionary type="Catalog" xmlns:pdf="http://xmlgraphics.apache/org/fop/extensions/pdf">
              <pdf:entry key="PageMode" type="name">FullScreen</pdf:entry>
              <pdf:entry key="PageLayout" type="name">SinglePage</pdf:entry>
              <pdf:dictionary type="normal" key="ViewerPreferences">
                <pdf:entry key="HideToolbar" type="boolean">true</pdf:entry>
                <pdf:entry key="HideWindowUI" type="boolean">true</pdf:entry>
                <pdf:entry key="DisplayDocTitle" type="boolean">true</pdf:entry>
                <pdf:entry key="NonFullScreenPageMode" type="name">UseThumbs</pdf:entry>
              </pdf:dictionary>
            </pdf:dictionary>
```

Comment: Could you tell me where inside the xsl-fo document you place this code? I'm putting it into the fo:declarations, using fop 2.1 but get `Unknown formatting object "{http://xmlgraphics.apache/org/fop/extensions/pdf}entry" encountered (a child of dictionary}. (Siehe Position 244:53)` - please

Comment: or what demonstrates it better `Unknown formatting object "{http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3}dictionary" encountered (a child of fo:declarations}. (Siehe Position 242:72)`

Comment: nevermind, trying to get it clear in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347687/does-fop-2-1-support-viewerpreferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by upgrading the ApacheFOP latest version 2.1.